# Voice Recognizer not present

Tags: android

I try this code

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
  new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
if (activities.size() != 0) {
  speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
} else {
  speakButton.setEnabled(false);
  speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
}
```

But the result it's Recognizer not present should i add any software to actice this service??

Comment: Are you trying this on a device or in an Emulator. I don't think it would work on emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my question. I installed "voice search" in the mobile with this code and this software need connection to work.